# Linking an image breaks slider

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

I'm using a [hybrid HTML/CSS/Java coding sheet](http://cssdeck.com/labs/imageslider-pager) that I copied and modified for my own use. So far, the customization has gone well except for trying to link images. The weird thing about it is, it only messes up when I link the first image. 
When I link the first image, none of them will show up. If I link only the second and third, all of the images show up and the last two slides even link. I have looked through many times and I still can't understand why it won't work. There isn't anything in the Javascript (that I can see) that doesn't allow links and being that they're simple `<li>` it seems like it should work normally. Any ideas?

This is the part I'm having issues with:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider_wrapper">
    <ul id="image_slider">
      <li><a href="Teddy-Bear-Pattern-Pack"><img src="/assets/SLC_SewingMachineThread_banner.jpg"></a></li>
      <li><a href="Teddy-Bear-Pattern-Pack">
        <img src="assets/SLC_TeddyBear_Pattern_Banner.jpg"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="Leather/Pre-Cut-Leather-Pieces/Oil-Tan-Pre-Cuts">
        <img src="assets/SLC_OilTan_PreCut_banner.jpg"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>                   
    <span class="nvgt" id="prev"></span>
    <span class="nvgt" id="next"></span>        
  </div>
```

Comment: @WillP img tag don't need closing tag...

Comment: Can you create a verifiable example where we can debug the problem? Either with a snippet on here or a JSFiddle.

Comment: Sorry if this is jumbled, JS Fiddle had me seperate the code in a way that I don't have it on my actual sheet. https://jsfiddle.net/wep1yvff/